# Example application that falls in the case of use of instagram permission

Tags: api, permissions, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to know an example application that falls in the case of using the 'public content' permission for instagram. The example may be just the conceptual, the application need not really exist.

> public_content: This permission (public_content) is only granted to
>   apps that enable brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers to
>   discover public content. We do not grant access to apps that do not
>   fall into these categories. Please review our documentation
>   (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten this permission for all my clients so I can give you some examples of answers to the application submission questions:

**Real Application Example:**

*Which use case best describes your Instagram integration?*

> My product helps **broadcasters and publishers discover content**, get
>   digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution.

*App Description:*

> MyApp provides social statistics to help brands and advertisers
>   understand and manage their audience. Additionally, MyApp provides
>   social statistic **to help broadcasters and publishers discover
>   content**.
>
> MyApp derives statistics from data publicly available on Instagram 
>   (e.g. number of media created in the last 14 days). These statistics
>   **help broadcasters and publishers discover content**.

**Fake (but likely to be accepted) Application Example:**

*Which use case best describes your Instagram integration?*

> My product helps **broadcasters and publishers discover content**, get
>   digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution.

*App Description:*

> MyApp analyzes relations between hashtags **to help brands and advertisers content**.
>
> MyApp derives relations based on hashtags used in medias' captions
>   allowing **brands and advertisers to discover** similar content.

**Why These Applications Fall into the `public content` Use Case**

They use a variant of the phrase "enable brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers to discover public content."

**General Tips**

In my experience, it's best to directly quote the Instagram API Documentation in your answers. Here are some more tips:

1. Keep answers brief and general.
2. Your answers should be about 33% direct quote from documentation (when I wasn't quoting, I was getting rejected).
3. Use no audio in your video and demo the exact feature described in your use case. Don't worry that it looks lame because of the sandbox, Instagram understands why the demo is sparse. They're mostly making sure you're application is production quality and not just plain HTML with not styling.

Comment: Are you sure about the putting brands and advertisers when we are using use case of broadcasters and publishers?